# Setting the Row Height dynamically in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a requirement, where I have to set the Row Height dynamically. For Example, the Input looks like - [image: Input line]

And I want my output to look like - [image: Output]

The String in that line will keep changing. So, now based on what characters, I should set the row height? Thanks. Kindly share your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Rows(4).Autofit
```

It will automatically resize the row hight, based on the contents of the cells in that row

Answer (score 2):

Use the `WrapText` property... like this:

```
Range("A4").WrapText = True
```